# Why can't people connect to my server app?

Tags: winapi, connection, client-server

I have a server written in C under Windows, but I can only seem to connect to it from machines that are also connected to the router my computer is connected to. Any ideas why? Here's my code:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

#define PORT "1234"
#define BUFLEN 512

DWORD ErrorMessage(char* msg, int error)
{
    printf("ErrorMessage: %s\nCodErr: %d\n", msg, error);
    return -1;
}

void PrintArray(char* v, unsigned int len)
{
        for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    printf("%c",v[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

DWORD WINAPI ClientHandler(LPVOID lpParam)
{
SOCKET ClientSocket = *((SOCKET*)lpParam);

char recvbuf[BUFLEN];

int iResult,iSendResult;

do
{
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, BUFLEN, 0);

    if(iResult > 0)
    {
        PrintArray(recvbuf,iResult);

        iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);

        if(iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return ErrorMessage("send",WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }

    else if(iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
    else
    {
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return ErrorMessage("recv",WSAGetLastError());
    }
}
while(iResult > 0);

return 0;
}

int main()
{
WSADATA wsaData;

int iResult;

iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);

if(iResult != 0)
{
    printf("WSAStartup failed and with error code: %d\n",iResult);
    return ErrorMessage("WSAStartup",GetLastError());
}

struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;

memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT,&hints,&result);

if(iResult != 0)
{
    printf("getaddrinfo failed %d\n",iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

if(ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return ErrorMessage("socket",WSAGetLastError());
}

iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return ErrorMessage("bind", WSAGetLastError());
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if(listen(ListenSocket,5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return ErrorMessage("listen",WSAGetLastError());
}

SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

sockaddr sa;

while(true)
{
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, &sa /*NULL*/, NULL);

    if(ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return ErrorMessage("accept",WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("New client arrived...\n");

    if(CreateThread(NULL, 0, ClientHandler, &ClientSocket, 0, NULL) == NULL)
        ErrorMessage("CreateThread",GetLastError());
}

iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket,SD_BOTH);

if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return ErrorMessage("shutsown",WSAGetLastError());
}

closesocket(ListenSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to forward the port from your router to the server running this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your program. The problem is in the configuration of your router.

Try to connect to some other TCP/IP service on your computer from outside.

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow your code, but usually I use `bind` with `htons`. In your code, it's not obvious how you convert your string "1234" into a numeric value. I wrote a very crude simple Web Server on port 1234 that just serves out a dummy "Hello World" page. All validation has been removed to keep the example short:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData = {0};
    WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData);
    SOCKET serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    SOCKADDR_IN sin = {0};
    sin.sin_family = PF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(1234);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(serverSocket, (LPSOCKADDR) &sin, sizeof(sin));
    listen(serverSocket, 1);
    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    while (clientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        char request[1024] = {0};
        recv(clientSocket, request, 1024, 0);
        static char html[] =
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html\n"
            "\n"
            "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Hello World!</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Hello World!</BODY></HTML>\n\n";
        send(clientSocket, html, sizeof(html), 0);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    }
    closesocket(serverSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My code is a modified version of the tutorial on winsocks from MSDN. Apparently it was because of my router. But your code might come in handy when I run into some other trouble. Thank you.